# DataOuput database implementation

Tags: java, jdbc

Is there an existing implementation of DataOuput for writing to a database instead of a file system. Would creating such a class be correct from a conceptual point of view.

Comment: No. Databases are not streams.

Comment: I don't want to use streams, just DataOutput.

Comment: What exactly is `DataOutput`?

Comment: Java interface java.io.DataOutput

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a BLOB field in a relational database you can write to it (for one record at a time) with an `OutputStream` (see [Blob.setBinaryStream()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Blob.html#setBinaryStream-long-)).

You can wrap this stream with a [DataOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#DataOutputStream-java.io.OutputStream-) which implements the `DataOutput` interface.

So technically it is possible to use a `DataOutput` to write to a database.

But why would one do that? The normal use case is to use columns and types provided by the database and not to hide the values inside a huge blob.
But maybe you have some rare and special circumstances.

Comment: Yes, I want to save the state of on object from an API that I use, but it can only write itself to a DataOuput.